# Getting class data without Hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate mapping:

I have below two classes:

```
class Employee{
    int empId;
    string name;
    float salary;
    Department dept;
    // ... getters and setters....
}


class Department{
    int deptId;
    string deptName;
    // ....and other details, getter and setters..
}
```

Now i have table for Employee only like

```
table Employee(EmpId number, Name varchar, salary number,deptId number)
```

There is not a need to keep table for `Department` as I am interested only in storing employee data with dept id.

I am looking `hibernate mapping` for many-to-one, one-to-one, one-to many but all required to store `dept data` in separate `table`.

My question:Is there a way to keep only only simple mapping file and where I can access `deptId` from `Department class` in `Employee mapping`?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define Department as a `component` if you use xml mapping (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html) or as an `@Embedded/@Embeddable` entity if you use annotations (§2.2.2.4 in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property)

Answer (score 0):

Dont make any association for field ***deptId***, treat ***deptId*** as simple attribute as like you are doing for ***salary*** field

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just need store deptId,  you don't need to create a Departement class.
Because in Hibernate, entity class is representated from Table in Database.

And may be, you can practice it, you try to remove `@Entity` annotation from Department class,
`@Entity` class, is annotation for the class to become a table in Database.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

```
Can I access dept Id from `Department` class in Employee mapping?
```

Imagine that once you stopped the program and started again ,You have an `department id` with you ,To whom you will ask for the `data of that Class` ??

No ,you have to do `mapping` for that and have to create corresponding columns in `DB` .

Answer (score 0):

Just map it as an Integer. You can still map it to the `DEPT_ID` column on `EMPLOYEE` table:

```
class Employee {
    ...

    @Column(name = "DEPT_ID")
    Integer deptId;

    ... getters and setters....
}
```